# Canvas vs Image for faux video player

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a server that generates pngs very rapidly and I need to make this into a poor-man's video feed. Actually creating a video feed is not an option.

What I have working right now is a recursive loop that looks a little like this (in pseudo-code):

```
function update() {
    image.src = imagepath + '?' + timestamp; // ensures the image will update
    image.onload = function () {update()};
}
```

This works, however after a while, it crashes the browser (Google Chrome, after more than 10 minutes or so). These images are being updated very frequently (several times a second). It seems the images are caching, which causes the browser to run out of memory.

**Which of these solutions would solve the problem while maintaining fast refresh:**

- HTML5 canvas with drawImage
- HTML5 canvas with `CanvasPixelArray` (raw pixel manipulation)

I have access to the raw binary as a Uint8Array, and the image isn't too large (less than 50 kb or so, 720 x 480 pixels).

**Alternatively, is there anyway to clear old images from the cache or to avoid caching altogether?**

EDIT:

Note, this is not a tool for regular users. It's a tool for diagnosing analog hardware problems for engineers. The reason for the browser is platform independence (should work on Linux, Windows, Mac, iPad, etc without any software changes).

Comment: I really can't see why would ANYONE want several PNG pictures per second on his browser. You should consider using an updating gif of some sort...

Comment: Think industrial-grade data. It's not something pretty for a normal user, but a tool for engineers to diagnose hardware problems. I'll edit my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crashing is due to http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=36142. Try creating object URLs (use XHR2 `responseType = "arraybuffer"` along with `BlobBuilder`) and revoking (using `URL.revokeObjectURL`) the previous frame after the next frame is loaded.

Edit: You really should be processing these into a live low-fps video stream on the server side, which will end up giving you greatly decreased latency and faster load times.

Comment: Will this avoid caching? I was under the impression that the image.src bug was because the browser was caching everything. I haven't read up on that, so I can't be sure.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, but it most likely isn't going to cache object URLs, as they are already local.

Answer (score 1):

@Eli Grey seems to have identified the source of your crashing. It looks like they have a fix in the works, so if you don't want to modify your approach hopefully that will be resolved soon.

With regard to your other question, you should definitely stick with `drawImage()` if you can. If I understand your intention of using the `CanvasPixelArray`, you are considering iterating over each pixel in the canvas and updating it with your new pixel information? If so, this will be *nowhere* near as efficient as `drawImage()`. Furthermore, this approach is completely unnecessary for you because you (presumably) do not need to reference the data in the previous frame.

Whether fortunately or not, you cannot directly swap out the internal `CanvasPixelArray` object stored within an HTML5 canvas. If you have a properly-formatted array of pixel data, the only way you can update a canvas element is by calling either `drawImage()` or `putImageData()`. Right now, `putImageData()` is much slower than `drawImage()`, as you can see here: http://jsperf.com/canvas-drawimage-vs-putimagedata. If you have any sort of transparency in the frames of your video, you will likely want to clear the canvas and then use `drawImage()` (otherwise you could see through to previous frames).

Having said all that, I don't know that you really even need to use a canvas for this. Was your motivation for looking into using a canvas so that you could avoid caching (which now doesn't seem to be the underlying issue for you)?

Comment: Yes, it was to avoid caching, because I thought that was the cause to my crashing. It would run for about 10 minutes or so, but then it would finally crash the entire browser (I'm assuming something in the kernel level got mad and kicked it).

Comment: Understood. Then yeah, I would recommend avoiding a canvas-based implementation unless you need to do work with the pixel data. If you don't need such functionality, adding a canvas element to the mix is unnecessarily increasing your overhead on an already time-sensitive application (as you probably already realize).

Comment: Yeah. It needs to be as real-time as possible. I think the updates are about 10 per second or so, but the images aren't large (something like 30k or so), so it takes a while to manifest the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the "movie" is data-driven (ie. based on numbers and calculations), you may be able to push MUCH more data to the browser as text and then have javascript render it client-side into a movie. The "player" in the client can then request the data in batches as it needs it.

If not, one thing you could do is simply limit the frames-per-second (fps) of the script, possibly a hard-coded value, or a slider / setable value. Assuming this doesn't limit the utility of the tool, at the very least it would let the browser run longer w/o crashing.

Lastly, there are lots of things that can be done with headers (eg. in the .htaccess file) to indicate to browsers to cache or not cache content.

Comment: It's technically data driven, but it's pretty complex, and sending all the data needed to compute it will be larger than the image itself. The png is generated from raw output from an analog device. There's a thin data layer over that, but ultimately it will be much more expensive to generate it on the client.

Answer (score 0):

iPad, you say ?.. Nevertheless, i would advice using Flash/video or HTML5/video.

Because WebKit is very easily crashed with even moderate influx of images, either just big images or just a huge number of small ones..

From the other side, XHR with base64 image data or pixel array MIGHT work. I have had short polling app, which was able to run for 10-12 hours with XHR polling server every 10 seconds.

Also, consider delta compression, - like, if its histogram with abscissa being time scale - you can only send a little slice from the rigth, - of course, for things like heat-maps, you cannot do that.

> These images are being updated very frequently (several times a
>   second).

.. if its critical to update at such a high rate - you MUST use [long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling).

Comment: I do use long polling, but I poll every time an image loads (like 10+ times a second).

Comment: Then its _short polling_ ? Because with long polling, interval between requests should be around 60 seconds.

Comment: See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling) for the definition I use for long polling. Long polling just means that the server waits to respond until the data is ready, then the client sends another request immediately.